# How to split lines from ip link show command?

Tags: python, regex, linux

So I have a output of a `ip link show` shell command. Now I want to slice it into groups.

Here is the text:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp7s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether f0:76:1c:35:7b:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether ac:b5:7d:0f:2d:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Lets say I want to slice it into 3 groups for each interface. First string will be everything that comes after 1: up to 2:, and so on.

I already tried:

```
(?<=\d: )\w+
```

But it cuts me only interface names.

How to do it with regex?

Comment: What is your exact output needed? Post it

Comment: Trivially, `lines = output.split('\n')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
(?<=\d: ).*\n+.+
```

you need to get the hole line - [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CclDdq/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe you wish to write an expression similar to:

```
(^\d+:(.*)[\r\n](.*))(?=^\d+:|$)
```

and you can remove the capturing groups, if unnecessary.

#### Test

```
import re

regex = r"(^\d+:(.*)[\r\n](.*))(?=^\d+:|$)"

test_str = """
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp7s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
link/ether f0:76:1c:35:7b:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
link/ether ac:b5:7d:0f:2d:6b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str, re.M))
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
> explained on the top right panel of
> [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/FTPZOW/1/). If you'd like, you
> can also watch in [this
> link](https://regex101.com/r/FTPZOW/1/debugger), how it would match
> against some sample inputs.

---

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/gnj36G/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-j` option to get JSON output so you don't have to do your own parsing.

```
import subprocess
import json

r = subprocess.run(['ip', '-j', 'link', 'show'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
result = json.loads(r.output)
for iface in result:
    print(f'interface {iface["ifname"]} mtu {iface["mtu"]} state {iface["operstate"]}')
```

Obviously, examine the JSON to see the names of the keys and choose which ones you need to pull out and process.  Here's a sample:

```
>>> result[0]
{'ifindex': 1, 'ifname': 'lo', 'flags': ['LOOPBACK', 'UP', 'LOWER_UP'], 
'mtu': 65536, 'qdisc': 'noqueue', 'operstate': 'UNKNOWN', 'linkmode': 'DEFAULT',
 'group': 'default', 'txqlen': 1, 'link_type': 'loopback', 
'address': '00:00:00:00:00:00', 'broadcast': '00:00:00:00:00:00'}
```

If you are on Python 3.6 or earlier, you need `universal_newlines=True` instead of `text=True`. The `f'...'` string format will also be unavailable in older Python versions (3.5 and earlier).

Generally speaking, with modern CLI tools, you should always look for a way to avoid implementing your own parser for their human-readable output. Older tools generally did not support XML or JSON (or etc) output, but many tools created in the last 15 or so years will offer at least some modest gestures towards a scriptable API.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `(?s)(?<=\n|^)\d+:.+?(?=\n\d|$)`

Explanation:

`(?s)` = single line mode: `.` matches also newline character

`(?<=\n|^)` - positive lookbehind: assert what preceeds is `\n` newline character or `^` beginnig of a string

`\d+:.+?` - match on or more digits `\d+`, then match semicolon `:`, then match one or more of any characters `.+?` (non-greedy)

`(?=\n\d|$)` - positive lookahead: assert what follows is newline followed by digit `\n\d` or end of a string `$`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccHgw2/1)